# What is the radius of the small circle inscribed in a square?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

If we are given a square with sides of length 4cm. The smaller circle is tangent to the larger circle and the two sides of the square as shown in the photo below. How can i find the length of the radius of the smaller circle?
My approach :

- The radius of the large circle is 2cm ( 1/2 length of the square side ).
- there is a right triangle( 45-45-90) where each leg is equal 2cm , and the hypotenuse( which is the segment from the center of the big circle passing through the center of the small one until the vertex of the square ) is 2$ \sqrt 2 $
- the segment that joins the radius of the small circle until the vertex of the square is equal -2+2 $\sqrt 2 $.
- I think in order to know the radius i have to subtract ( -2+2$\sqrt2 $- x ) where x is the small space between the vertex of the square and the arc of the small circle. 
  Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the upper right corner of the square. The smaller circle is the image of the larger circle by a homothetic transformation centered at $A$. The ratio of this transformation is $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1}$ because the farthest point from $A$ in the large circle is at a distance $2(\sqrt{2} + 1)$ and its image is the nearest point from $A$ which is at distance $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Hence the radius of the smaller circle (assuming the larger circle has radius 2) is $2 \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1} = 6 - 4 \sqrt{2}$

Comment: But excuse me, is there another solution using elementary euclidean geometry ? because actually my course book is about euclidean geometry only. Thank you

Comment: I am writing one. Let me mention that homothecy is a rather Euclidean transformation too. But we say 'similar triangles' instead of 'homotheted, rodated[ and mirrored]'. Try to think of the circles as of similar objects. Maybe inscribe them into similar triangles. The solution is very neat and indeed Euclidean, but uses some "advanced" techniques, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Let $E$ be the center of the square, $F$ the middle of $BC$, $G$ the intersection of the larger circle with $CE$. Let $IH$ be the tangent line to the circle at the point $G$, with $I\in CD$, $H\in BC$. Then the desired circle is inscribed in $\triangle ICH$ -- it touches $BC$ and $CD$ obviously and (let $J$ be it's center) $J\in CG$, while $CG$ being the bisector of $\angle HCI$ of equilateral (by symmetry) $\triangle HCI$ ant therefore it's height, so $CG\perp HI$, $J\in CG$ $\Rightarrow$ the smaller circle touches $HI$ in $G$ $\Rightarrow$ the two circles share a common tangent therefore are touching $\Rightarrow$ the smaller sircle is the desired circle.

Let $EF=1$, $N$ be the intersection of line, perpendicular to $EF$, passing though $E$ with the tangent $IH$; $M$ be intersection $EF$ and $IH$. In right triangle $GEM$ $\angle GEM=45^\circ$ $\Rightarrow EM=\sqrt{2}$ $\Rightarrow FM=\sqrt{2}-1$.
Let $x=CK$ be the desired radius. $FH=FM=\sqrt{2}-1$, from right $\triangle HJK$: $JK=HK\cdot\tan 22.5^\circ$ so $HK=x/\tan 22.5^\circ$ and finally $FH+HK+KC=1$ $\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2}-1+x(1+1/\tan 22.5^\circ)=1$.
$\tan 22.5^\circ$ is obtainable from $\tan 2\alpha=\frac{2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha}=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}
=\tan 45^\circ=1$.
Hence we get $x = \dfrac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{1 + \sqrt{\frac{2 + \sqrt{2}}{2 - \sqrt{2}}}}=3-2\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Thank you ! So helpful 

Answer (score 1):

From the centre of the large circle until vertically above it is equal to $2$ but is also equal to $(2+r)\sin 45+r=\sqrt2 +r(\frac{2+\sqrt2}{2})$ where r is the radius of the smaller circle. This simplifies to $$r(\frac{2+\sqrt2}{2})=2-\sqrt2$$
which rearranges to $$r=\frac{2(2-\sqrt2)}{2+\sqrt2}=\frac{2(2-\sqrt2)^2}{4-2}=6-4\sqrt2$$
That is your answer.